# Why are mutations not persistent

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

```
const Todo = mongoose.model("ToDo", {
    text: String,
    complete: Boolean
});
const yoga = createYoga({
    schema: createSchema({
        typeDefs: `
            type Query {
                todos: [Todo]
            }
            type Todo {
                id: ID!
                text: String!
                complete: Boolean!
            }
            type Mutation {
                createTodo(text: String!): Todo
                updateTodo(id: ID!, complete: Boolean!): Boolean
                removeTodo(id: ID!): Boolean
            }
        `,
        resolvers: {
            Query: {
                todos: () => Todo.find()
            },
            Mutation: {
                createTodo: async (_, { text }) => {
                    const todo = new Todo({ text, complete: false });
                    todo.save();
                    return todo;
                },
                updateTodo: async (_, { id, complete }) => {
                    Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { complete });
                    return true;
                },
                removeTodo: async (_, { id }) => {
                    Todo.findByIdAndRemove(id);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },
    }),
    graphiql: {
        title: 'To-Do Application',
        defaultQuery: `{}`,
    },
    graphqlEndpoint: '/',
})
```

In GraphQL playground:

I can create a todo item.
I can query all items in my todo list

I cannot update or delete an item from the list. My query afterward returns my initial list.

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Comment: I guess you need to await or use callback when you are trying to save, update or remove Todo

Comment: Sorry ... that was the initial code. I removed it while troubleshooting. It did not work either

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `.save()` function on a [Mongoose model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) is async, so you have to await it

So add `await` in front of your `todo.save()`, `Todo.findByIdAndUpdate()` and  `todo.findByIdAndRemove()`

Comment: That was the initial code. I removed it while troubleshooting. Using await did not help either.